# Add new element to existing JSON array with jq

Tags: arrays, json, bash, jq

I want to append an element to an array in a JSON file using the ``` jq``add ``` command, but it's not working.

`report-2017-01-07.json` file:

```
{  
   "report": "1.0",
   "data": {  
      "date": "2010-01-07",
      "messages": [  
         {  
            "date": "2010-01-07T19:58:42.949Z",
            "xml": "xml_samplesheet_2017_01_07_run_09.xml",
            "status": "OK",
            "message": "metadata loaded into iRODS successfully"
         },
         {  
            "date": "2010-01-07T20:22:46.949Z",
            "xml": "xml_samplesheet_2017_01_07_run_09.xml",
            "status": "NOK",
            "message": "metadata duplicated into iRODS"
         },
         {  
            "date": "2010-01-07T22:11:55.949Z",
            "xml": "xml_samplesheet_2017_01_07_run_09.xml",
            "status": "NOK",
            "message": "metadata was not validated by XSD schema"
         }
      ]
   }
}
```

I am using this command:

```
$ cat report-2017-01-07.json 
| jq -s '.data.messages {"date": "2010-01-07T19:55:99.999Z", "xml": "xml_samplesheet_2017_01_07_run_09.xml", "status": "OKKK", "message": "metadata loaded into iRODS successfullyyyyy"}'
jq: error: syntax error, unexpected '{', expecting $end (Unix shell quoting issues?) at <top-level>, line 1:
.data.messages {"date": "2010-01-07T19:55:99.999Z", "xml": "xml_samplesheet_2017_01_07_run_09.xml", "status": "OKKK", "message": "metadata loaded into iRODS successfullyyyyy"}               
jq: 1 compile error
```

Here's how I want the output to look:

```
{
    "report": "1.0",
    "data": {
        "date": "2010-01-07",
        "messages": [{
            "date": "2010-01-07T19:58:42.949Z",
            "xml": "xml_samplesheet_2017_01_07_run_09.xml",
            "status": "OK",
            "message": "metadata loaded into iRODS successfully"
        }, {
            "date": "2010-01-07T20:22:46.949Z",
            "xml": "xml_samplesheet_2017_01_07_run_09.xml",
            "status": "NOK",
            "message": "metadata duplicated into iRODS"
        }, {
            "date": "2010-01-07T22:11:55.949Z",
            "xml": "xml_samplesheet_2017_01_07_run_09.xml",
            "status": "NOK",
            "message": "metadata was not validated by XSD schema"
        }, {
            "date": "2010-01-07T19:55:99.999Z",
            "xml": "xml_samplesheet_2017_01_07_run_09.xml",
            "status": "OKKKKKKK",
            "message": "metadata loaded into iRODS successfullyyyyy"
        }]
    }
}
```

Comment: Don't know this well but is it not an issue that .data.messages is an arrray? So you need something like .data.messages.[]

Comment: sorry, did not work

Comment: Ok - read the docs and installed jq (on have Windows here) and tried - get same error as you. Looks like Windows shell has issues with the way it feeds double quotes into the stream which trips up jq. Could not get anything to work so no answer to your question but you might want to look at escaping the double quotes in the jq command. So `"date"` would become `\"date\"` etc.

Comment: if I use this command I can update all the date attributes. `jq '.data.messages[].date = "2010-01-07T99:99:99.999Z"' report-2017-01-07.json` but I cannot add yet.

Comment: I updated with the output

Answer (score 176, accepted):

The `|= .+`  part in the filter adds a new element to the existing array. You can use `jq` with filter like:

```
jq '.data.messages[3] |= . + {
      "date": "2010-01-07T19:55:99.999Z", 
      "xml": "xml_samplesheet_2017_01_07_run_09.xml", 
      "status": "OKKK", 
      "message": "metadata loaded into iRODS successfullyyyyy"
}' inputJson
```

To avoid using the hardcoded length value `3` and dynamically add a new element, use `. | length` which returns the length, which can be used as the next array index, i.e.,

```
jq '.data.messages[.data.messages| length] |= . + {
      "date": "2010-01-07T19:55:99.999Z", 
      "xml": "xml_samplesheet_2017_01_07_run_09.xml", 
      "status": "OKKK", 
      "message": "metadata loaded into iRODS successfullyyyyy"
}' inputJson
```

(or) as per peak's suggestion in the comments, using the `+=` operator alone

```
jq '.data.messages += [{
     "date": "2010-01-07T19:55:99.999Z",
     "xml": "xml_samplesheet_2017_01_07_run_09.xml", 
     "status": "OKKK", 
     "message": "metadata loaded into iRODS successfullyyyyy"
}]'
```

which produces the output you need:

```
{
  "report": "1.0",
  "data": {
    "date": "2010-01-07",
    "messages": [
      {
        "date": "2010-01-07T19:58:42.949Z",
        "xml": "xml_samplesheet_2017_01_07_run_09.xml",
        "status": "OK",
        "message": "metadata loaded into iRODS successfully"
      },
      {
        "date": "2010-01-07T20:22:46.949Z",
        "xml": "xml_samplesheet_2017_01_07_run_09.xml",
        "status": "NOK",
        "message": "metadata duplicated into iRODS"
      },
      {
        "date": "2010-01-07T22:11:55.949Z",
        "xml": "xml_samplesheet_2017_01_07_run_09.xml",
        "status": "NOK",
        "message": "metadata was not validated by XSD schema"
      },
      {
        "date": "2010-01-07T19:55:99.999Z",
        "xml": "xml_samplesheet_2017_01_07_run_09.xml",
        "status": "OKKK",
        "message": "metadata loaded into iRODS successfullyyyyy"
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

Use [jq-play](https://jqplay.org/) to dry-run your `jq-filter` and optimize any way you want.

Comment: Since the goal is just to append an element, it would be better to use += but it is worth noting that `.data.messages[3] |= . + X` can here be simplified to `.data.messages[3] = X` as the `.` on the RHS is effectively just `null`.

Comment: (windows JQ user here): I wonder if it is possible to write this new data to the same (input) file, instead of creating a temporary file which needs to be renamed afterwords..

Comment: @script'n'code - Using `sponge` is probably still the best option if you have it or can install it (it's part of moreutils).

Comment: @peak  how can I insert that object to the beginning of the array, couldn’t figure out . Thanks

Comment: @peak how can I specify the order when inserting the element to the array ?

Answer (score 75):

Rather than using `|=`, consider using `+=`:

```
.data.messages += [{"date": "2010-01-07T19:55:99.999Z",
   "xml": "xml_samplesheet_2017_01_07_run_09.xml",
   "status": "OKKK", "message": "metadata loaded into iRODS successfullyyyyy"}]
```

#### Prepend

On the other hand, if (as @NicHuang asked) you want to add the JSON object to the beginning of the array, you could use the pattern:

```
 .data.messages |= [ _ ] + .
```

Comment: Prepend example: `echo '{"arr": [ "data1" ]}' | jq '.arr |= ["data2"] + .'` => `{"arr": ["data2", "data1"]}`

Answer (score 50):

Summary:   ". +"  is your saviour

Details:

For adding an entry to a list: You can append [list1] + [list2]  (and not [list]  + data)

```
$ echo '[ "data1" ]' | jq '. + [ "data2" ]'
[
  "data1",
  "data2"
]

$ echo '[ {"key1": "value1"} ]' | jq '. + [{"key2": "value2"}]'
[
  {
    "key1": "value1"
  },
  {
    "key2": "value2"
  }
]
```

For adding a key/value to a dictionary:

```
$ echo '{"key1": "value1"}' | jq '. + {"key2": "value2"}'
{
  "key1": "value1",
  "key2": "value2"
}
```

References:

https://gist.github.com/joar/776b7d176196592ed5d8