# How to move images of docker in aufs directory to overlay2?

Tags: linux, docker

I update my kernel of Debian from 3.x to 4.x.
Docker storage become overlay2.

```
ls /var/lib/docker/ 
containers  image  network  overlay2  plugins  swarm  tmp  trust  volumes
```

old directory structure is

```
aufs  containers  graph  image  init  linkgraph.db  network  plugins  repositories-aufs  swarm  tmp  tmp-old  trust  volumes
```

My images is in aufs directory, I can not start docker service with old directory. how can I move my images to overlay2?

Comment: Stack Overflow is a site for programming and development questions. This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about programming or development. See [What topics can I ask about here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) in the Help Center. Perhaps [Super User](http://superuser.com/) or [Unix & Linux Stack Exchange](http://unix.stackexchange.com/) would be a better place to ask.

Comment: Get it. Thank you.

Answer (score 9):

1. Identify the images to save and restore after migrating from aufs to overlayfs2.
2. Export all the images to be migrated to overlayfs into one archive - this is faster and efficient

   `sudo docker save $IMAGES -o /data/save.tar`

   Here `IMAGES` is a variable containing the image names
3. Create /etc/docker/daemon.json with following contents:

   ```
   {
     "storage-driver": "overlay2"
   }
   ```

   [ Refer to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42245288/add-new-element-to-existing-json-array-with-jq/57537190#57537190 for updating it using jq ]
4. Take the backup of the directory where docker images are stored and delete the directory

   `mv /var/lib/docker/images /var/lib/docker.aufs.images`
5. `systemctl daemon-reload`
6. `systemctl restart docker`
7. `docker load < save.tar`

Comment: Should the command really be `mv /var/lib/docker /var/lib/docker.aufs.images` ? Is it not `mv /var/lib/docker/images /var/lib/docker.aufs.images` ? And for consistency, all commands should be executed with `sudo ...` ? Just asking

Comment: What about volumes. *Those* are usually the actual precious data that cannot be recreated.

Comment: All my containers are now missing, i need to move more than images!

Comment: There is this french page, which provides some scripts to migrate all images: https://www.sylvaincoudeville.fr/2019/12/docker-migrer-le-stockage-aufs-vers-overlay2/
I experienced that all my previous containers are missing after migration, like @Brunis noticed earlier. As I did not found a solution to this, you'll need proper compose configs (or so) for your containers, in order to restart them after migrating the images.

Answer (score 3):

based on fuenfundachtzig and pr-pal post

1. Check your current storage -driver

   `sudo docker info | grep -i storage`

   return Storage Driver: aufs
2. Backup all docker stuff

   `sudo systemctl stop docker`

   `sudo cp -au /var/lib/docker /var/lib/docker.bk`

   `sudo systemctl start docker`
3. Identify the images to save and restore after migrating from aufs to overlayfs2

   `mkdir -p /data`

   `sudo sh -c 'docker images > /data/list_images.txt'`
4. Export all the images to be migrated to overlayfs into one archive - this is faster and efficient

   Here `IMAGES` is a variable containing the (uniq) image names

   `IMAGES=$(sudo docker images | sed '1d' | awk '{print $3}' | uniq)`

   `for c in $IMAGES; do echo $c; sudo docker save -o /data/$c.tar $c ; done`
5. `sudo systemctl stop docker`
6. Change Storage drive from aufs to overlayfs2

   Create or modify /etc/docker/daemon.json with following contents:

   if the file is already there, add line as following

   ```
   {
       "storage-driver": "overlay2"
   }
   ```

   if the file is empty, you can go with

   ```
   sudo sh -c " echo '{ \"storage-driver\" : \"overlay2\" }' > /etc/docker/daemon.json "
   ```
7. `systemctl daemon-reload`
8. `sudo systemctl restart docker`
9. Restore docker images

   ```
   IMAGES=$( cat /data/list_images.txt | sed '1d' | awk '{print $3}' | uniq)
   for c in $IMAGES; do sudo docker load -i /data/$c.tar; done
   ```
10. Check your new storage driver

    `sudo docker info | grep -i storage`

    return Storage Driver: overlay2
11. Remove backup of docker directory

    `sudo rm -rf  /var/lib/docker.bk`

Answer (score 2):

A big caveat is that the docker save/load solution mentioned in the answers here will strip all your tags.

Make sure to take a copy of the full images list first:

```
docker images >images.txt
```

and use it after to restore all the tags:

```
cat images.txt | sed '1d' | awk '{print "docker tag "$3" "$1":"$2}' | /bin/bash
```

You may need to edit images.txt if you had any  tags and remove them and/or fix those manually.

Answer (score -1):

You can actually set the storage driver to use. It is possible that the upgrade has changed a default file or configuration to `overlay2`. You may be able to change it back to `aufs`. The documentation on this is at https://docs.docker.com/engine/userguide/storagedriver/selectadriver/#check-and-set-your-current-storage-driver.

Also, depending on the Docker version you are running, the setting could be in `/etc/default/docker` instead of `/etc/docker/daemon.json`.

Comment: But I want to use overlay2 instead of aufs.

Comment: Ah, that will actually be a bit more complex. Are you only looking to save the images or do you also need to save the containers that were started from the images?

Comment: @AndyShinn how do i transfer the containers also?

Comment: @Brunis that sounds like a good new question for Stack Overflow