# How can I duplicate multiple times an existing object within a JSON array using jq?

Tags: jq

I have the following json file:

```
{
  "actions": [
    {
      "values": "test",
      "features": [
        {
          "v1": 100,
          "v2": {
            "dates": [
              "2020-04-08 06:58:26",
              "2020-04-08 06:58:26"
            ]
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

I would like to append n-times the object within the "actions" array to the end of it, creating n+1 total objects.

Expected output if n=2:

```
{
  "actions": [
    {
      "values": "test",
      "features": [
        {
          "v1": 100,
          "v2": {
            "dates": [
              "2020-04-08 06:58:26",
              "2020-04-08 06:58:26"
            ]
          }
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "values": "test",
      "features": [
        {
          "v1": 100,
          "v2": {
            "dates": [
              "2020-04-08 06:58:26",
              "2020-04-08 06:58:26"
            ]
          }
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "values": "test",
      "features": [
        {
          "v1": 100,
          "v2": {
            "dates": [
              "2020-04-08 06:58:26",
              "2020-04-08 06:58:26"
            ]
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

I found this answer [[How can I duplicate an existing object within a JSON array using jq?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48983196/how-can-i-duplicate-an-existing-object-within-a-json-array-using-jq/48984894#48984894?newreg=356f704a5eb343c195ffb51f6709e224]) however it only works with one element at the end.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can just use a `reduce()` function with `range()` together to create the index to include the object at.

```
jq --arg n 2 'reduce range(0, ($n|tonumber)) as $d (.; .actions[$d+1] += .actions[0] )' json
```

Comment: Thank you! It is exactly what I was looking for.

Comment: @ana: if this worked, please click on the tick-mark next to answer to mark the post "resolved". See [What does it mean when an answer is "accepted"?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer) and [What should I do when someone answers my question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)