# Transforming JSON array

Tags: json, ansible, jq

I need to conditionally transform a list of objects defined in a JSON file. The problem with the playbook is that I need the transformation to yield either the value of `docker.network` or `id`. Simply put, I need to figure out some kind of ternary operator for transforming lists. The playbook results in:

```
"msg": "['baz', AnsibleUndefined]"
```

I need

```
"msg": "['baz', 'bar']"
```

**Playbook:**

```
vars:
  daemons: "{{ lookup('file','./test.json') | from_json }}"

  tasks:
    - name: Transform
      debug:
        msg: "{{ daemons | map(attribute='docker.network')  }}"
```

**test.json:**

```
[
  {
    "id": "foo",
    "docker": {
      "network": "baz"
    }
  },
  {
    "id": "bar",
    "docker": {
    }
  }
]
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For example

```yaml
    - debug:
        msg: "{{ _list }}"
      vars:
        _list: "{{ _list_str|from_yaml }}"
        _list_str: |
          [
          {% for i in daemons %}
          {% if i.docker.network is defined %}
          {{ i.docker.network }},
          {% else %}
          {{ i.id }},
          {% endif %}
          {% endfor %}
          ]
```

gives

```yaml
  msg:
  - baz
  - bar
```

Answer (score 1):

You should process your file `test.json` for example using `jq`

```
jq 'map(. |= if .docker.network then . else . + {"docker":{"network": .id}} end)' test.json
```

will print

```
[
  {
    "id": "foo",
    "docker": {
      "network": "baz"
    }
  },
  {
    "id": "bar",
    "docker": {
      "network": "bar"
    }
  }
]
```

You can read more in pages:

https://kaijento.github.io/2017/03/26/json-parsing-jq-simplifying-with-map/
https://stedolan.github.io/jq/manual/#Math
[Add new element to existing JSON array with jq](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42245288/add-new-element-to-existing-json-array-with-jq)

And test your command on page:

https://jqplay.org/

Comment: test.json is the input data not the expect result. The result should only consist of the value of either docker.network or id.

Comment: So you can use jq to transform streams not files. ( with linux pilelines )