# How to add a package to "replace" section of "composer.json" using CLI?

Tags: composer-php, command-line-interface

How can I add a package to the `replace` section of `composer.json` using cli?

For example `composer require vendor/package` adds a package to the `require` section.

In composer [docs](https://getcomposer.org/doc/04-schema.md#replace), I did not find anything like `composer replace vendor/package` command.

Comment: If the documentation does not mention this, why not simply open the file and edit it by hand?

Comment: when necessary, I edit the file `composer.json`. But I am looking for an elegant solution. Preferably out of the box. I need this for the same reason the `composer require` exists. It is more convenient, simpler, there is no need to check for duplication and so on.

Answer (score 2):

Editing the `replace` section of `composer.json` is not currently supported via the CLI.

Neither editing `conflict`, for that matter.

The complete list of CLI options is listed [here](https://getcomposer.org/doc/03-cli.md).

You could use something like `jq` to do it if for some reason you need to do it programmatically via the CLI ([e.g.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42245288/add-new-element-to-existing-json-array-with-jq)), but more often than not is the kind of thing a developer adds manually to their `composer.json` when needed.

Comment: thanks for the answer, in general I agree with you, but maybe there will still be an elegant solution via the CLI or the question will attract the attention of composer developers.