# append json array using jq

Tags: bash, shell, jq

I have a json file which I am fetching from consul and the results are very simple:

`[ { "name" : Jon", "class" : "senior" } ]`

I want to update the array with below json:

`{ "name" : santa", "class" : "christmas" }`

and the output should be:

`[ { "name" : Jon", "class" : "senior" },  { "name" : santa", "class" : "christmas" } ]`

This looks very simple but I am unable to do it till now.

this is what I have been trying with `jq`:

```
JSON=[{ "name" : Jon", "class" : "senior" }]

echo $JSON | jq '.[] += { "new_key" : "new_value" }'
```

I followed some answers on stackoverflow but most of them are about adding a single element.

Comment: if you have input `[ { "name": "Jon", "class": "senior" } ] { "name": "santa", "class": "christmas" }` then filter `input as $first | $first+[input]` should work. https://jqplay.org/s/YsSEXxiWbQ

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are several issues with your script. Generally, this should work (but still needs improvement on certain levels):

```sh
JSON='[{"name": "Jon", "class": "senior"}]'
echo "$JSON" | jq '. += [{"new_key": "new_value"}]'
```

```json
[
  {
    "name": "Jon",
    "class": "senior"
  },
  {
    "new_key": "new_value"
  }
]
```

Answer (score 2):

This question is likely a duplicate of [Add new element to existing JSON array with jq](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42245288/add-new-element-to-existing-json-array-with-jq).

Anyway as a shortcut, here is how you do it without piping the source JSON array:

```sh
JSON='[{"name": "Jon", "class": "senior"}]'
jq --null-input --argjson  a "$JSON" '$a  + [{"name" : "santa", "class" : "christmas" }]'
```