# How to add dependencies into package.json with jq

Tags: node.js, bash, ubuntu, jq, package.json

I want to add package dependencies to the `package.json` file by `bash` script using `jq`.

[Add new element to existing JSON array with jq](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42245288/add-new-element-to-existing-json-array-with-jq)

Here is the test script with 5 steps:

```
#!/bin/bash

add_element_with_jq() {
    
    # step 1: Add a new root element "{}" first
    echo "============= step 1 ================"
    
    echo "{}" > "package.json"
    
    # step 2: Add a "dependencies" sub element to the root element "{}"
    echo "============= step 2 ================"
    # step 3: Add a "foo" package with version "1.1.1" to the "dependencies"
    echo "============= step 3 ================"
    
    jq '. += dependencies {
      "foo": "1.1.1"
    }' "package.json"
    
    echo "=========== step 3 output =================="
    cat "package.json"
    
    # step 4: Add a "bar" package with version "2.2.2" to the "dependencies"
    echo "============= step 4 ================"
    
    jq '.dependencies += 
      "bar": "2.2.2"
    ' "package.json"
    
    # step 5: If the "foo" package already existed, then update to the latest version. Otherwise, add the "foo" package to the dependencies.
    echo "============= step 5 ================"
    
    jq '.dependencies += 
      "foo": "3.3.3"
    ' "package.json"
    
    echo "=========== final output =================="
    cat "package.json"
}

add_element_with_jq
```

Here is the error:

```
============= step 1 ================
============= step 2 ================
============= step 3 ================
jq: error: syntax error, unexpected '{', expecting $end (Unix shell quoting issues?) at <top-level>, line 1:
. += dependencies {                  
jq: 1 compile error
=========== step 3 output ==================
{}
============= step 4 ================
jq: error: syntax error, unexpected ':', expecting $end (Unix shell quoting issues?) at <top-level>, line 2:
      "bar": "2.2.2"           
jq: 1 compile error
============= step 5 ================
jq: error: syntax error, unexpected ':', expecting $end (Unix shell quoting issues?) at <top-level>, line 2:
      "foo": "3.3.3"           
jq: 1 compile error
=========== final output ==================
{}
```

Here is the expected output:

```
=========== step 3 output ==================
{
  "dependencies": {
    "foo": "1.1.1"
  }
}
=========== final output ==================
{
  "dependencies": {
    "foo": "3.3.3",
    "bar": "2.2.2"
  }
}
```

What's wrong in my `bash` function, and how to fix the `jq` commands?

Comment: Where is step 2?

Comment: maybe add_element_with_jq() is have an syntax using function keyword?

Comment: Only step 3 has code because I think the `jq '. += dependencies` should add the "`dependencies`" to the "`{}`". So I just split the description into Step 2 and Step 3. The two steps  are using the same code under step 3.

Comment: `dependencies` without quotes and a colon is not valid JSON. I'm guessing you mean `"dependencies": { ... }` but we obviously can't know for sure what you actually hoped it would do.

Comment: `jq` doesn't modify its input in-place; you would have to write the output of each command back to `package.json`.

Comment: Is it not possible to use npm/yarn/etc to add the dependencies via script?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, all you need is this:

```bash
cat <<'.' >package.json
{
   "dependencies": {
      "foo": "3.3.3",
      "bar": "2.2.2"
   }
}
.
```

But let's assume you have a reason to break it down into steps.

---

The linked answer is about adding to an array. You are not trying to add to an array. To add a key and value to an object, you can simply use

```
.object["key"] = value
```

Therefore, doing one addition at a time, the program would look like the following:

```
{ } |
.dependencies = { } |
.dependencies[ "foo" ] = "3.3.3" |
.dependencies[ "bar" ] = "2.2.2"
```

[Demo](https://jqplay.org/s/8qYJdvg7Ixz) on jqplay.

As separate calls to `jq`, we get the following:

```bash
printf '{ }\n' |
jq '.dependencies = { }' |
jq '.dependencies[ "foo" ] = "3.3.3"' |
jq '.dependencies[ "bar" ] = "2.2.2"' >package.json
```

As a single pipeline, these commands are still entangled. To separate them, we will need a temporary file or the `sponge` command-line utility.

```bash
printf '{ }\n'                                          >package.tmp1.json
jq '.dependencies = { }'              package.tmp1.json >package.tmp2.json
jq '.dependencies[ "foo" ] = "3.3.3"' package.tmp2.json >package.tmp3.json
jq '.dependencies[ "bar" ] = "2.2.2"' package.tmp3.json >package.tmp4.json

mv package.tmp4.json package.json
rm package.tmp{1,2,3}.json
```

What if you wanted to add `.dependencies` only if it didn't already exist? Replace

```
.dependencies = { }
```

with

```
.dependencies //= { }
```

Comment: @stackbiz Why'd you remove the quotes? BAD!

Answer (score 1):

The syntax being used (`. += dependencies`) seems incorrect.

To add or modify a key in `dependencies`, use the following syntax:

```
jq '.dependencies["foo"]="1.1.1"' "package.json"
```

This will output the edited contents. Since we cannot pipe back into the file (it is open for reading while `jq` is being executed), we have to pipe it to a new file and rename it (use the `mv` command for this).

```
jq '.dependencies["foo"]="1.1.1"' "package.json" > package.json.new \
&& mv package.json.new package.json
```

Comment: Or `jq '...' package.json | sponge package.json`